# DOMPDF ZF2 page numbers

Tags: zend-framework2, dompdf

I'm new to ZF2 and i wanted to create a pdf file with DOMPDF module.

It is happening fine and i wanted to enhance it with page numbers.
I checked the documentation how to do it but i got a bit confused on how should i implement it to the Controller and what should i write in the view.

I set the configuration as well: `def("DOMPDF_ENABLE_PHP", true);`

And added this line in my view:

```
<script type="text/php">
 if ( isset($pdf) ) {
    $font = Font_Metrics::get_font("helvetica", "bold");
    $pdf->page_text(72, 18, "Header: {PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}",
                    $font, 6, array(0,0,0));
 }
</script>
```

but nothing shown up.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your document fully formed? With dompdf inline script has to appear in the body. If your content isn't surrounded by a body element the script blocks will be moved into the document head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this way its works perfectly:

```
#footer .page:after { 
    content: "-" counter(page) "-"; 
}

<div id="footer">
    <p class="page"><?php $PAGE_NUM ?></p>
</div>
```